# Can I change SQL Server resource pool settings at any time?

Tags: resource-governor

I have set up a custom resource pool `TestResourcePool` with the following values:

```
MIN_CPU_PERCENT=50,  
MAX_CPU_PERCENT=80,  
CAP_CPU_PERCENT=100,  
MIN_MEMORY_PERCENT=0,  
MAX_MEMORY_PERCENT=100,  
MIN_IOPS_PER_VOLUME=500,  
MAX_IOPS_PER_VOLUME=2000
```

I would like to arrive at a correct number for these parameters by iteratively changing the values and running the read write queries. Can I dynamically change it when my tests are running?